# How to remove a row from a table based inside the Ajax response success function

Tags: jquery

On click of a checkbox , i am displaying a confirmation box and once clicked ok on the Confirmation box , i am deleteing a record in the database with the help of Ajax call , based on he ajax call response i am removing the record from the table

But this line is not removing the row

```
 $(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

could anybody please let me know how to resolve this 
This is my code

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var respfromserver = 'success' ;

    if (confirm("Are You Sure Want to Delete this Particualr Record?") == true) {
        var empid = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(empid);
        if (empid) {
            empid = empid.trim();
            var employeeinfo = {
                'empid': empid
            };
            var employee_information = JSON.stringify(employeeinfo);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'test',
                success: function(data) {
                if(respfromserver==='success')
                {
                    alert('into success');
                     $(this).closest('tr').remove();    

                }
                    else
                    {
                        this.checked = true;
                    }


                },

            });
        }
    } else {
        this.checked = true;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vxe2d2hh/15/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your `this` is refering to the Ajax object.
If you want to refer to the `this` object of the event, you'll have to store the `this` in a variable, and reuse it in the ajax call.

Ex:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    var $that = $(this);
...
$that.closest('tr').remove();
...
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vxe2d2hh/16/

Comment: this is working good , what about else part  this.checked = true; , should i need to change it this also ?? (If in case errorr has occured in ajax call )

Comment: please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vxe2d2hh/19/ , i have chnaged the responsefrom server from success to something else

Comment: Yes you will have to change this part too. But as `$that` is a jquery object in my exemple, use the jquery function : `$that.prop('checked', true);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('#' + empid).closest('tr').remove();
```

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vxe2d2hh/17/)

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

**into**

```
$this.closest('tr').remove();
```

*p/s : `$(this)` inside success block is refer to callback, not the checkbox that was click*